# fabric.js how to add rectangle adjacent to rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working to put rectangles representing solar panels on roof top of a given house. User can rotate a rectangle to align it with roof. Code is working fine until an adjacent rectangle is added without rotating the selected panel. However, I am facing problem in correctly calculating the position of a new rectangles adjacent to the rotated rectangle. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Panel Positioner</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var solar_panel = {"width": 57, "height": 94}; // Default pixles on 5M zoom
                var offset = 58;
                var rads = 0;
                var position = {};
                var id = 1;
                $('#add-panel').click(function() {
                    addPanel();
                });
                function addPanel() {
                    if (id === 1) {
                        canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
                        canvas.on("after:render", function() {
                        canvas.calcOffset();
                        });
                        canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
                            var activeObject = e.target;
                            position.x = activeObject.get('left');
                            position.y = activeObject.get('top');
                        });
                        canvas.on('object:rotating', function(e) {
                            var activeObject = e.target;
                            var angle = activeObject.get('angle');
                            rads = (activeObject.get('angle') * Math.PI / 180.0);
                        });
                    }
                    var markerPt2 = position;
                    markerPt2.x += offset * Math.cos(-rads);
                    markerPt2.y -= offset * Math.sin(-rads);
                    rect = new fabric.Rect({
                        id: id,
                        left: markerPt2.x,
                        top: markerPt2.y,
                        fill: 'grey',
                        width: solar_panel.width,
                        height: solar_panel.height,
                        borderColor: 'black',
                        stroke: '#000',
                        lockScalingX: true,
                        lockScalingY: true,
                        hasRotatingPoint: true,
                    });
                    rect.set('angle', rads * 180.0 / Math.PI);
                    id++;
                    canvas.add(rect);
                    canvas.renderAll();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="c1" width="800" height="600" style="z-index:1000; border: 2px solid black;" ></canvas>
        <input type="button" id="add-panel" name="add-panel" value="Add Panel" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a bit of work around I found out what as wrong with my own script.
There are two important things involved:

1. When an object is rotated, only the radians change (NOT the x,y position). So, after rotating an object, we only have to calculate its radians to find out where the next adjacent object will be laid out. So, in my code what I am doing wrong is that after either object movement or rotation, I am re-calculating the new object's x,y coordinates. So, what needs to be done is a boolean flag that will decided whether the object was rotated. If yes, then do not re-calculate the x,y position for new adjacent object. Just re-calculate the radians (which is already being implemented in "object:rotating" block). So the code should look like:

   ```
   if(rotated == false) {
       markerPt2.x += offset * Math.cos(-rads);
       markerPt2.y -= offset * Math.sin(-rads);
   } else {
       rotated = false;
   }
   ```
2. Additionally another fact that has been annoying for me was when an object is rendered or moved in Fabric.js, its x,y position is top-left corner of surrounding rectangle, but as an object is rotated, Fabric.js returns the center point of object as its x,y position. So in this case when the object was rotated, the Fabric.js translated point jumped to center point of rectangle. So when implementing "object:rotating" only lastly recorded (before rotation) x,y should be used.